# __gmon_start is executed before _start

Tags: linux, x86, elf

When I analyze `/usr/bin/diff` with `gdb`, I see that `__gmon_start__` is being called before `_start` for some reason. Every document I have found so far has been claiming that `_start` is the entry point of a program; and the entry point field in the ELF header also points to the address of `_start`.

Why does `diff` not start executing with `_start`; and where is that information held?

Comment: `_start` is the *default* entry point.  `ld -e foobar -o a.out in.o` will look for the symbol `foobar` in `in.o`, and set the ELF entry point address to address that symbol ends up having in the final object file.  Note that the ELF entry point is an address, not a name, in the final file.  Have a look with `readelf -a /usr/bin/diff`.  IDK your `diff` was built with `__gmon_start` as the symbol name containing the entry point.  I'm not an expert on this, but I think mine is too (Ubuntu 15.10).

Comment: The entry point address that was specified in the ELF header belongs to `_start`, but `__gmon_start__` is called before it.

Comment: Where did your `diff` binary come from (distro/version/architecture)?  my `/usr/bin/diff` doesn't have a `_start` symbol in `nm -a` or `nm -aD` output, because it's stripped.  Maybe you should edit in the steps you took to get the info you drew your conclusions from.  That might help someone explain things, esp. if you misinterpreted something.

Comment: By binary belongs to an Ubuntu 14.04 32-bit distribution and definitely has a `_start` symbol at 0x80497d0. When I debug the binary with `gdb`, I put breakpoints on `main`, `_start`, `__gmon_start__`, `__libc_start_main` etc. and `run`. The first encountered breakpoint belongs to `__gmon_start__`. It is then followed by `_start`, `__libc_start_main`, then `__gmon_start__` again, and `main`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Every document I have found so far has been claiming that _start is the entry point of a program

For fully-static executable, this is true.

For a dynamically linked executable, the user-space executions starts at the `_start` symbol of the loader (`ld.so`), and there are usually 10s of thousands of instructions and many system calls executed before the loader calls `_start` in the `a.out`.

In the process of getting to `_start` in `a.out`, functions from the main executable could be called (and that's what you are observing).